# swift / CoreData - Create "dummy" NSManagedObjecIDs for data models (to test things without the need of managed objects)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Say I have 2 `NSManagedObject`s in `CoreData`.

```swift
class House: NSManagedObject {}
class Location: NSManagedObject {}
```

I also have data model `structs` like this:

```swift
struct HouseModel {
    var objectID: NSManagedObjectID
    ...
}

sruct LocationModel {
    var objectID: NSManagedObjectID
    ...
}
```

For each loaded `managedObject` I basically use its attributes to initialize a new model struct to use for the UI and stuff (mainly collection views)

I have to have the `NSManagedObjectID` attribute in the `structs` in order to be able to make changes to the `managedObject` that struct belongs to. (I learned that I should use the `mainViewContext` only for reading while using something like `persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask` for writing. Thus, I need the `NSManagedObjectID` to load the objects on a background queue)

That's working but there is a problem with this approach:
I can't initialize one of these data models without a `managed object`. That's annoying when I want to create dummy data for UI testing or unit testing.

I know one solution: Create a `Dummy` `managedObject` with exactly one instance and use its objectID for stuff like that. But I don't really like this. Is there a better / more convenient way?

I mean, I would love to entirely remove the `objectID` attribute to keep `CoreData` separate from these model `structs`. But I don't see a way to do this. I need the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For passing `NSManagedObjects` to a detail view for editing, it is often useful to do that on a new main queue managed object context, which simplifies your UI access and allows you to throw away the context if the user cancels changes.

But that's not what you asked.

Your problem is that you want to identify a managed object, but not use `NSManagedObjectID`. For this, you can use a `URL` property instead. `NSManagedObjectID` has a `uriRepresentation()` that returns a URL, and `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` can convert a URL back into a managed object ID using `managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation:)`. So you can store any old URL in the struct for testing purposes, and still be securely referring to managed objects in your app logic.